# How to remove duplicate items present in scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I have the following code in which I used local storage to store array of Product varient ID when user hits compre on every product description page.:

**"Prdvar"** contains product variants ID's (ex: 10,13, etc.,)

```
a.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')));
    localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
    $scope.dataVarID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));

    alert($scope.dataVarID); //Duplicate values present

    $scope.CompareProduct = function()  {

        a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
        a.push("{ ProductVarient :"+Prdvar+"}");
        alert(a);
        localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));

     };
```

My question is how to remove duplicate items present in $scope.dataVarID.

```
,{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :33}
```

// I dontknow at 
    first , is adding then 12,13,12,12

I need only `,{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :33}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map and filter out the duplicates

```js
//$scope.dataVarID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
function getUniqueArrayObject(array) {
    var result = array.map(function(a) {
        return a.ProductVarient;
    });
    var unique = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
        if (unique.indexOf(result[x]) == -1) unique.push(result[x]);
    }
    return (unique.map(function(a) {
        return {
            ProductVarient: a
        };
    }))
}
var newArray = getUniqueArrayObject([{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :33}])
console.log(newArray)
// $scope.newArray=getUniqueArrayObject($scope.dataVarID);
```

Comment: parameter to function is $scope.dataVarID.?

Comment: $scope.dataVarID is the array containing duplicate values? If so, yes.

Comment: TypeError: [object Array] is not a function am getting error.

Comment: Mark answer as accepted if it helped you @PrashanthHarish

Comment: your code works fine. But in my local variable value I dont know it iseems not in array format. After fixing my issue I will sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to angular,

I recomment you to use `lodash` `uniq` function to do that:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniq

Answer (score 0):

Use http://underscorejs.org/

Include to your project, this library is very helpful for array manipulations.

```
var arrray = [{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :33}]

var result = _.map(_.groupBy(ar,function(doc){
  return doc.ProductVarient;
}),function(grouped){
  return grouped[0];
});
```

> Result is: [{ ProductVarient :5},{ ProductVarient :33}]